# How to re-apply or re-render my JTable after editing the JTable's JSpinner cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a problem on applying a `DefaultTableRenderer` to a `JTable` which I set to contain `JSpinner` and `JComboBox` through the use of `DefaultCellEditors`

I have created a simple `DefaultTableRenderer` that checks if there's a duplicate time or invalid time value as shown below.

```
public class ScheduleTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int col) {

        Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);

        Object startTimeValue = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1);
        Object endTimeValue = table.getModel().getValueAt(row,2);
        if(startTimeValue!= null && endTimeValue != null && 
                startTimeValue.toString().equals(endTimeValue.toString()) ){
            System.out.print("Start Time: "+startTimeValue+", ");
            System.out.println(endTimeValue+"\n");
            cellComponent.setBackground(Color.RED);
            ((JLabel)cellComponent).setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        }

        if(row%2 == 0){
            cellComponent.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            ((JLabel)cellComponent).setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        else{
            cellComponent.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            ((JLabel)cellComponent).setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        return cellComponent;
    }

}
```

I'd like to color the rows red if the user selects a time which is a duplicate or conflict with another. **The rendering or changing of row color must occur after user selects a time and moves to the next column**.

I have tried to re-apply my DefaultRenderer to refresh the row colors if **startTime** is equals with **endTime** but it's not working. I guess I'm doing it wrong.

[image]

I have attempted to re-apply the renderer I created when JSpinner's state is changed but with no luck.

```
public class ScheduleTimeCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    private final JSpinner spinner;
    private final SpinnerDateModel spinnerDateModel; 

        public ScheduleTimeCellEditor(JTable jtblSchedule) {
            super(new JTextField());
            this.jtblSchedule = jtblSchedule;
            spinnerDateModel = new SpinnerDateModel();
            spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                jtblSchedule.setDefaultRenderer(new ScheduleTableCellRenderer);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What is the simplest way I can achieve this.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: If you could create and post a valid [mcve] (please read the link), code posted here that we could compile and run unaltered, that would probably help you get a decent answer quickly. Please ask if any questions about this valuable tool.

Comment: 1) Don't keep creating a new JTextField when you do the rendering. The point of using a renderer is to reuse the same component to be efficient. 2) Also, do keep assigning a new ChangeListener to the spinner. Both of the above should be done once in the constructor of the class. 3) Don't keep resetting the renderer. The renderer need logic to compare the time of the two columns. 4) add a TableModelListener to the TableModel. When data is change you want to invoke repaint() on the table so all the rows are repainted. Then if your renderer has the proper logic to highlight a row it should work.

Comment: Instead of creating  a custom renderer you may want to check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) which shows how to color a row based on data in the row.